# Change wrapper background dynamically in a loop with javascript with custom delays

Tags: javascript, css, loops, asynchronous, settimeout

I would like to change page background in an infinitive loop with a custom delays between each change with help of javascript.
I ran into few problems:

When I test it without loop first, for some reason both functions fire up at same time:

```
setTimeout(myFunction_1, 3000);
setTimeout(myFunction_2, 3000);

function myFunction_1(){                
document.getElementById("wrapper").style.background = "green";
console.log("test 1");
}

function myFunction_2(){                
document.getElementById("wrapper").style.background = "yellow";
console.log("test 2");
}
```

An when I add loop:

```
while (1 == 1){
setTimeout(myFunction_1, 3000);
setTimeout(myFunction_2, 3000);
}
```

it crashes the browser...

How do change the background in a loop with custom time intervals without crashing the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that u r not familar with js things, u'd better dive into them first.

You should change your code as below:

```
myFunction_1();

function myFunction_1(){                
    document.getElementById("wrapper").style.background = "green";
    console.log("test 1");
    setTimeout(function(){
        myFunction_2();
    },3000);
}

function myFunction_2(){                
    document.getElementById("wrapper").style.background = "yellow";
    console.log("test 2");
    setTimeout(function(){
        myFunction_3();
    },3000);
}

function myFunction_3(){                
    document.getElementById("wrapper").style.background = "blue";
    console.log("test 3");
    setTimeout(function(){
        myFunction_1();
    },3000);
}
```

Comment: What if I have N backgrounds, can I chain them all in a similar fashion?

Comment: I changed the code to fit with three functions. You'd better give a data array or something to show how u organize your colors and time gaps. So that I can decide the architecture of the code.

Comment: My data is in php array, and javascript will be created dynamically with php. I think I can work with what you already gave me. You are right, I am new to js and just started to learn :)